# How to add tags to outgoing email in Mandrill ( An email services from Mailchimp)?

Tags: php, email, header, smtp, mailchimp

I am using mandrill to send email, and I follow the guidelines here:

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582147-How-to-Send-with-PHPMailer

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'MANDRILL_USERNAME';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'MANDRILL_APIKEY';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

...and send the email

However, there is a tag option available in API, 
I would like to add tag to track the email :

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html

```
'tags' => array('password-resets')
```

The problem is, can I add tags without include their API file, e.g. add the tags at the header in phpmailer?

Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this variant with PHPMailer class:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader('X-MC-Tags:password,some_other_tag');
```